# inserção de saldo no db apenas apos confirmação

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou fazendo um sistema para controle de despesas/receitas, e quero saber como fazer os valores da receita ou despesa se somarem ao saldo apenas após a confirmação do pagamento.
Ex: cadastro uma conta de luz para pagar no valor de R$ 100,00 no para daqui a uma semana. Meu saldo atual é de R$ 200,00, mas eu só quero que o valor da conta de luz seja descontado do saldo apenas quando eu marcar a conta de luz como paga. Como posso fazer isso usando apenas PHP?

Comment: Eu acho que você tem um problema de especificação. Não faz sentido você salvar o saldo no banco. Você já tem as receitas e despesas, o saldo deve ser sempre um valor calculado somando as receitas e subtraindo as despesas.

Comment: concordo com o problema da especificação... uma conta à pagar, é apenas um registro, um documento, e não um movimento financeiro, no movimento sim, você pode gravar o saldo.

Comment: acho que deveria entrar como despesas no ato do efetivo pagamento, antes disso é Contas a Pagar

Comment: ps. Eu gravo o saldo na minha tabela de movimentação, uma vez que ela não sofre updates ou delete, apenas inserts, então tenho as colunas, `valor`, `saldo_anterior`, `saldo_atual` que são preenchidas por subselect dentro do insert ou por trigger